# Retrieving Latitude & Longitude CoOrdinates, Displaying in UILabel

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, mkmapview

I am interested in grabbing my users current Latitude and Longitude coordinates, and displaying them literally as a NSSString in a UILabel on the view.

I don't need any MKMapView or to show anything graphically, just to display the coordinates in a UILabel.  Is this possible?

Could anyone provide a starting block for me?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Ya, its possible. Just import `#import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>` and declare the delegate `<CLLocationManagerDelegate>`. then you can get the values in following delegate mathod.

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation{

    CLLocationCoordinate2D location=newLocation.coordinate;
    NSString *s = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f,%f",location.latitude,location.longitude];
}
```

Comment: Thank you, i'll try and implement that this evening. Im assuming I can then just assign the NSString to a UILabel with location.text = s; ?

Comment: ya its enough. The NSString have the latitude and longitude value separate by coma(,).

Comment: For some reason I can't get it to display in the UILabel. It compiles without issue but it just doesn't populate the UILabel

Comment: Check the string weather it is having the values or not by using `NSLog(@"\t %@",s);`

Answer (score 0):

There is the **CoreLocation** framework which does this job. You can get the user's current location by implementing this delegate.

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager
didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation
       fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
```

Answer (score 0):

Follow the steps:

- Add MapKit.framework to your project
- add to .h  #import "CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h" and #import "MapKit/MapKit.h"
- Use delegates as, @interface yourInterface : UIViewController < MKMapViewDelegate, CLLocationManagerDelegate >

Now Add following method to your .m file

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
{  
[self setMapCenter:newLocation.coordinate];
[self._mapView selectAnnotation:[[self._mapView annotations] lastObject] animated:YES];
lblLong.text = [nsstring stringWithFormat:@"%f", newLocation.coordinate.longitude];
lblLat = [nsstring stringWithFormat:@"%f", newLocation.coordinate.latitude];
[self.locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];
}

-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
NSLog(@"ERROR");
}
```

Here mention `CLLocationManager *locationManager;`. good luck.